# SQLite callback efficient solution

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I would like to run a series of SQLite queries using JavaScript. These queries get the latest update timestamp of several tables. For example:

```sql
SELECT last_updated FROM students ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT last_updated FROM docs ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT last_updated FROM logs ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT last_updated FROM requests ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then I would send these last_updated timestamps to the server. When I think of how to do this, I would use something like this:

```js
var message = {};
sql('QUERY 1',[],function(row){
    message.q1 = row.shift().shift(); // first row, first item
    sql('QUERY 2',[],function(row){
        message.q2 = row.shift().shift();
        sql('QUERY 3',[],function(row){
            message.q3 = row.shift().shift();
            sql('QUERY 4',[],function(row){
                message.q4 = row.shift().shift();
                $.ajax('submit.php',{ // tell the server these things.
                    data: message,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log('Server replied: '+response+'\n');
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('HUHU.\n');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This will work but I find this very inefficient becaue of the nested SQL calls. There might also be cases wherein I need the data from 10 different tables.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: It might help to clarify what you mean by "efficient"

Comment: that's a good point. from the developer's perspective, it's irritating to close all those braces and parenthesis. at the same time, this seems like hard-coded because you cannot easily comment out some queries or add new queries. not to mention the indentions you have to make if you want clean codes :)

Answer (score 0):

For such nested constructs you can use something like **[step](https://github.com/creationix/step)**.

It will allow you to use syntax like:

```
Step(
  function readSelf() {
    fs.readFile(__filename, this);
  },
  function capitalize(err, text) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return text.toUpperCase();
  },
  function showIt(err, newText) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(newText);
  }
);
```

Comment: And how would this be applied to the problem in the question?

Comment: You won't have so much nested calls.

Comment: I was asking for example code specific to this question, or something like that. As far as I can tell, WebSQL does not match the interface expected by step.

Comment: With *what* modifications?

Comment: I'm answering to @rationalboss. If you have further questions about how you can apply my answer feel free to ask and I'll answer you (as question, not comment). You can also ask me politely in the chat :-).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is do the calls "in parallel", and use a "barrier" pattern to see when they are done.

```
var calls_to_go = 4;
var callback = function(){
   calls_to_go -= 1;
   if(calls_to_go <= 0){
     do_ajax_stuff();
   }
}

sql('QUERY 1',[], callback);
sql('QUERY 2',[], callback);
sql('QUERY 3',[], callback);
sql('QUERY 4',[], callback);
```

Of course, this particular code is just to give an idea. If you use one of those async programming libraries they should all have some feature for making writing this sort of thing more pleasant and if you still want to do things by hand you should make sure that things are more organized, that the "4" isn't hardcoded, and so on.