# Do I need Web Workers for looping AJAX-requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-worker

Given: a php-script for parsing portions of data on a web-site. It parses about 10k products hence rather slow.

I need to make a web-frontend with html/css/js for it. I made a loop which makes ajax-requests and shows progress inforamtion. It uses syncronous ajax because it needs to wait until another request is done to perform another.

```
 do {
    var parseProductsActive = true;
    var counter = 0;
    myAjax('parseProducts.php?start='+counter, false, function(resp) {
        if (resp[0]=='s') {
            counter += Number(resp.substring(1));
            parseProductsActive = false;
        }
        else {
            counter += Number(resp);
        }   
        self.postMessage(counter);  
    });
 } while (parseProductsActive==true);
```

I'm doing it in a Web Worker because I'm afraid it's going to hang up the interface because of this endless loop and (a)synchronousness of ajax itself won't help to solve the prolem.

But when I tried to use ajax in a web worker I found it's hard though possible because jQuery doesn't work in a Web Worker at all. It uses DOM even for non-DOM operations and DOM isn't available in a Web Worker. And many developers doubt using Web Workers at all. I just wanted to ask if I am doing it right or wrong. Is there any more surface solutions to that I can't see?

Comment: Can you AJAX your records in, say, 100 at a time, and update the display dynamically, without using the Web Worker?

Comment: Isn't it the same I'm talking about? How won't it hang on the page? If we write it with a loop.

Comment: No, you grab 100 records (AT ONCE) in asynch (real AJAX), display them, then go fetch another 100 after the first request completes.

Comment: >then go fetch another 100 after the first request completes.
What do you mean by "then"? Where do I write it? Do you propose recursive callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed right: a recursive callback is the way to do a bunch of asynchronous requests in sequence. It might look a bit like this:

```
var parseProductsActive = true;
var counter = 0;

//define the loop
function doNextAjax(allDone){
   //Instead of just returning, an async function needs to 
   //call the code that comes after it explicitly. Receiving a callback
   //lets use not hardcode what comes after the loop.

  if(!parseProductsActive){
    allDone();
  }else{
    //use async Ajax:
    myAjax('parseProducts.php?start='+counter, true, function(resp) {
        if (resp[0]=='s') {
            counter += Number(resp.substring(1));
            parseProductsActive = false;
        }
        else {
            counter += Number(resp);
        }   
        self.postMessage(counter);

        doNextAjax(); // <---
    });
}

//Start the loop
doNextAjax(function(){
  console.log("the code that runs after the loop goes here")
});

//BTW, you might be able to get rid of the "parseProductsActive" flag with a small
// refactoring but I'm keeping the code as similar as possible for now.
//It would be kind of equivalent to writing your original loop using a break statement.
```

Yes, its ugly and verbose but ints the only way to do it in raw Javascript. If you want to write a more structured version that looks like a loop instead of something with tons of gotos, have a look at one of the async control flow libraries or one of the compilers that compiles extensions of Javaascript with async support back into regular JS with callbacks.

Comment: Still, are Web Workers bad? Not for a general user, considering it's not supported in older browsers, but for a single user who will use the parser. Can my solution take place?

Comment: You could use webworkers here but it wouldnt be that helpful. The point of webworkers is to let you do lots of intensive JS processing in a separate thread but in this case you are doing little processing and lots of waiting for the server to respond. Finally, if what you care about is being able to write the code using a loopp instead of recursion, then using a CPS compiler is a more straightforward and compatible solution.

Comment: Another question. What if we have a bunch of ajax requests not in a sequence but rather running in parallel physically? Can I run parallel ajax-requests without web workers so that I could benefit from paralelizing in performance?

Comment: You will need webworkers if you want to use more than one thread/core at a time. However, if you are doing something similar to what you have now, where there is little processing and lots of waiting, then you can do everything cooperatively with callbacks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15204642/90511

Comment: I tried this but though they finished in different order they worked the same time as if run synchronously. Where as runing them with web workers or with iframes gave me huge performance benefit. Kind of weird. Where can I read about ajax'es realizations in all the details?

Comment: @German: You might wasnt to consider asking a new question for that. I cant think of a good link out of the top of my head. All I can say is that Javascript uses a single threaded event loop model with cooperative concurrency. (btw, are you sure that you are doing your ajax asynchronously? maybe you forgot to change that flag)

Comment: I am. They run in different chaotic order after all, as I've said. Thank you for help anyway.